# Failed to resolve Firestore Android Studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was following a tutorial for Firestore but then this error occured, I have all the necessary things in my project level Gradle file, I checked the other questions similar to mine, and mine isn't the same scenario. Could you please help?

> ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.1

App lvl Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.blindnews.kimh2.blindnews"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, please change the following lines of code:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:18.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
```

In your top level `build.gradle` file please be sure to have the latest version of Google Service plugin:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
```

Comment: Thanks! I did such a silly mistake, should've updated everything :(